# % style macros not supported in some C++/CLI project property pages under VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros, c++-cli, resx

We're currently evaluating VS2010 and have upgraded our VS2008 C++/CLI project to the new .vcxproj format.  I've noticed that a certain property we had set in the project settings did not get translated properly.  Under Configuration Properties -> Managed Resources -> Resource Logical Name, we used to have (in VS2008) the setting:

```
$(IntDir)\$(RootNamespace).$(InputName).resources
```

which indicated that all .resx files were to compile into

```
OurLib.SomeForm.resources
```

inside of the assembly. (the Debug portion is dropped when assembled)

According to MSDN, the $(InputName) macro no longer exists and should be replaced with %(Filename).  However, when translating the above line to swap those macros, it does not seem to ever expand.  The second .resx file it tries to compile, I get a "LINK : fatal error LNK1316: duplicate managed resource name 'Debug\OurLib.%(Filename).resources".  This indicates to me that the % style macros are not being expanded here, at least in this specific property.

If we don't set anything in that property, the default behavior seems to be to add the subdirectory as a prefix, such as:

```
OurLib.Forms.SomeForm.resources
```

where Forms is the subdir of our project that the .resx file lives.  This only occurs when the .resx file is in an immediate subdirectory of the project being built.  If a .resx file exists somewhere else on disk (aka ..\OtherLib\Forms\SomeForm2.resx) this prefix is NOT added.

This is causing an issue with loading form resources, as it does not account for this possible prefix, even though we are using the standard Forms Designer method of getting at resources:

```
System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(SomeForm::typeid));
```

and do not specify the .resources file by name.

The issue I've just described may not be the same as the original question, but if I were to fix the Resource Logical Name issue I think this would all go away.  Does anyone have any information about these % macros and where they are allowed to be used?

Comment: It appears than you can specify the compiled name for each individual .resx file in order to get this behavior.  %(Filename) works there but not for the global setting I was trying to change.  This is slightly annoying.